# Checking missing value consistency and filling it

Tags: pandas, data-science, missing-data

How to check if missing tuple in dataframe which is related to another column has non missing value the column which can be mapped using another column?

Suppose if i have two columns X and Y. X -> Y. How to check if all y has missing value for that x. And if there is inconsistency like one value of y has NaN which maps to x2 but another tuple in y which maps to x2 does not have NaN. How to place this value in NaN